Is there any Nativescript library available which validates OKTA tokens?
Is there any Nativescript library available which would validate OKTA tokens locally?
I am using TnsOAuthClient but it doesn't has any method which validates token locally.
Tried TnsOAuthClient client library and it doesn't has any method which validates access token locally.
